# Wrapping a string buffer

Tags: c++, string, templates

We have a large C++ real-time program that uses buffers (e.g. `char str[500]`) of different sizes to store strings.

Due to some memory leakages we had in the past, we want to wrap the strings with a `MyString` class that would be initialized with the buffer and the size.

The problem is how to efficiently and easily allocate the buffers and the wrapper together, while keeping the buffer allocated as part of the class, and not allocated from the heap (see the next example).

I've tried using a template in the following manner:

```
template <unsigned int N>
class BufferString : public MyString
{
public:
   BufferString() : MyString(m_buf, N) { }
   char m_buf[N];
};
```

So it could be allocated as class member or as an automatic variable:

```
class SomeClass
{
   BufferString<500> m_str;   // Need the buffer to be allocated in SomeClass
};

void foo()
{
   BufferString<350> str;     // Need the buffer to be allocated on the stack
}
```

However, the executable size grows dramatically using this solution, by about 1kB per instantiation of the template (probably due to the compilation of the constructor).

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

---

EDIT: I've found an implementation similar to my proposed solution called `fixed_char_buf` (by John Panzer, found [here](http://www.johnpanzer.com/tsc_cuj/ToolboxOfStrings.html)).

Another implementation and reasoning for this method is found [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-string-performance/184405453).

Comment: Can't you just use `std::string` ?

Comment: Don't adapt your implementation to any memory leakage problems, as you write, you had. Address the memory leakage problems first and then make the most of dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Is there any special requirement why it must not be allocated on heap? The solution you provided is IMO the only one which is able to allocate it on stack. Youll have to live with the size drawback then.

Comment: Side note: Don't use names like `__buf`, starting with two underscores. They are [reserved](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html).

Comment: @DesmondHume Sure I fixed the memory problems I've found, but to make sure they won't repeat, I want to add some protection mechanism. We are not using dynamic allocation because in real-time applications the allocation is time consuming.

Comment: @Shahbaz Thanks. I'll fix my example.

Comment: @yoshigev, what real-time platform are you using? As you said, dynamic memory allocation breaks real-time. On the other hand, allocating everything on the stack is a very bad idea since you may unexpectedly cause a stack overflow. The best practice is to pre-allocate all your memory **before** your real-time threads start (dynamic allocation here is fine), then use them without having to allocate any other memory.

Comment: @Shahbaz We are already allocating all the classes using pools. But since we want to able to monitor the sizes of the pools, we would like the buffers to be part of the classes. If we use dynamic allocation, we would have no (easy) way to associate a buffer with its class (to calculate its size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like the most logical and precise way when using templates.  As suggested by [Torsten Robitzki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346512), try stripping debug symbols from your executable.

Depending on your compiler, particularly older compilers for real-time embedded systems, templates can quickly bloat the binary size.  If this is the case, there are a few options that avoid templates:

- Implement an allocation strategy.  If `BufferString` is written properly, then the memory it owns (`m_buf`) could be allocated on the stack or heap without introducing leaks.  If fragmentation and time, not memory leaks, are the primary reasons to avoid the heap, then there are numerous allocation patterns to consider that are specifically designed to mitigate these issues on real-time systems, such as pool or static allocation patterns.
- If the heap *must* be avoided, and templates are causing too much bloat, then the other alternative is manually declare the buffer and `MyString` separately.  Although I would try to avoid it as much as possible, macros may provide a suitable compromise between usability and readability.  For example, the following macro could be used to declare an automatic variable:

  ```
  #define BUFFER_STRING(name, size)  \
    char name##buffer[size];         \
    MyString name(name##buffer, size)
  ```

Comment: Thanks. It seems I'll have to decide between using macros (memory efficient) and using templates (convenient), as no other solution was proposed. I'll also test how the template affect the stripped binary.

Answer (score 0):

Strip the debug symbols from your executable. 1k per instance is probably no the code of the c'tor, but debug symbols.